# GeoSpark show SQL results fails

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin, geospark

I am using GeoSpark 1.3.1 where I am trying to find all geo points that are contained in a POLYGON. I use the sql command:

```
val result = spark.sql(
    |SELECT *
    |FROM spatial_trace, streetCrossDf
    |WHERE ST_Within (streetCrossDf.geometry, spatial_trace.geometry)
    """.stripMargin)

result.show()
```

The query works fine but, fails when I try to show the result. Seems like an output issue from the library. I am doing this in zeppelin notebook. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.? I get error below:

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 10.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 10.0 (TID 15, 10.42.22.236, executor 3): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.ArrayData
at org.apache.spark.sql.geosparksql.strategy.join.TraitJoinQueryExec$$anonfun$toSpatialRdd$1.apply(TraitJoinQueryExec.scala:164)
at org.apache.spark.sql.geosparksql.strategy.join.TraitJoinQueryExec$$anonfun$toSpatialRdd$1.apply(TraitJoinQueryExec.scala:163)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1334)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:214)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1334)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$aggregate$1$$anonfun$22.apply(RDD.scala:1122)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$aggregate$1$$anonfun$22.apply(RDD.scala:1122)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$36.apply(SparkContext.scala:2157)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$36.apply(SparkContext.scala:2157)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm a bit late, but this is addressed by the developer [here](https://gitter.im/geospark-datasys/Lobby?at=5aa85dacf3f6d24c6870896e). The geometries need to be converted using a [constructor](https://sedona.apache.org/api/sql/GeoSparkSQL-Constructor/)

Example fix:

```
WHERE ST_Within (ST_GeomFromWKT(streetCrossDf.geometry), ST_GeomFromWKT(spatial_trace.geometry))
```